# GetMethod() returns null

Tags: c#, invoke, getmethod

I have a class of queries in

```
public class gridQueries
{
    ....

    public string propertiesCombinedNamesQuery { get; set; } =
        "SELECT [NameId], [CombinedName] AS Display FROM [Names] ORDER BY [CombinedName]";
    ....
}  // end class gridQueries
```

In another method, I get the string of the name of this query and then try to invoke it, but the `GetMethod()` always returns `null`.

```
// Get the short name of the dependent field from the dictionary value[2] string
string _1DF_Name = addEditFieldControl.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value[1].Contains(fieldShortName)).Key;
// Find the long name of the dependent field
string Value1Text = addEditFieldControl.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key.Contains(_1DF_Name)).Value[1];
```

This gives me a string that looks like this
    "_Q_propertiesCombinedNamesQuery_OwnerName"

```
// Couldn't get invoke to work.
// because MethodInfo info is null after the GetMethod() call

string queryMethod = "";
queryMethod = "queries."+strIsBtwTags(Value1Text, "_Q_", "_");
Type queriesType = queryMethod.GetType();
MethodInfo info = queriesType.GetMethod(queryMethod);

string query = info.Invoke(null, null).ToString();
```

Can anyone spot what am I doing wrong?
Or suggest a way to invoke this string as a method so that I get the return string with the `SQL` query in it?

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: `propertiesCombinedNamesQuery` isn't a method, for one. It's a property. Also, most of the code here is irrelevant. Either, `queryMethod` is containing the wrong string (and hence the question would be unrelated to `GetMethod`), or it's containing the *correct* string, but `GetMethod` returns null; in which case you can simply hardcode it as a simplified example, and remove the irrelevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I converted my property statement into a method statement (Thank you John Doe in comment above)

From:

```
public class gridQueries
{
    ....
    public string propertiesCombinedNamesQuery { get; set; } =
        "SELECT [NameId], [CombinedName] AS Display FROM [Names] ORDER BY [CombinedName]";
    ....
}
```

To:

```
public class gridQueries
{
    ....
    public string propertiesCombinedNamesQuery() 
    {
        return "SELECT [NameId], [CombinedName] AS Display FROM [Names] ORDER BY [CombinedName]";
    }
    ....
}
```

From my program, I invoke the method

```
// Top of program
using System.Reflection;
....
....
string qstring = "propertiesCombinedNamesQuery";
string query = ""

gridQueries q2 = new gridQueries();
MethodInfo methodInfo = q2.GetType().GetMethod(qstring);
query = (string)methodInfo.Invoke(q2, null);
....
```

query now contains `SELECT [NameId], [CombinedName] AS Display FROM [Names] ORDER BY [CombinedName]`

This works.

What I was missing was passing the class name as the first parameter of the Invoke statement.